# Attempt to present *ViewController* on <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fce13803600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have a Facebook login button on my app's login page. The web-view part of the log-in proceeds without a hitch, but all it does is change the Facebook button title to `"Log Out"`, instead of progressing with presenting the next view controller.

Here is the log:

```
Attempt to present <ViewController: 0x7fce11c29450> on <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fce13803600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here's the code I'm using to log into facebook:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
        connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "email, id, first_name, last_name, gender, birthday, name, picture.width(480).height(480)"])) { httpResponse, result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                if let resultDictionary = response.dictionaryValue {
                    AuthService.sharedInstance.loginFacebookUser(userDetails: resultDictionary as NSDictionary, completion: { (result) in
                        if result == "Success" {
                            self.goToMovies()
                        } else {
                            self.alert(result)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    self.alert("There was an error logging in with Facebook. Please try again.")
                }
            case .failed:
                self.alert("There was an error logging in with Facebook. Please try again.")
            }
        }
        connection.start()
    }
```

And here is the implementation for `goToMovies()`, the function where I instantiate the view controller I want to present:

```
func goToMovies() {
        let progressViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProgressViewController") as! ProgressViewController
        self.show(progressViewController, sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in similar posts ? There are quite a lot of questions that mention the issue *"Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"*

Comment: @nathan yes I have. I always end up with the same problem.